# Can we use sockets to connect to the server for indefinite time for notifications?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, websocket, notifications

I am developing a winform application.I need to implement real time notifications into it.After searching a lot on the net, I have found out that it can be done using web-sockets technology.But creating sockets is also a way of creating a bidirectional connection with the server.So,can't we just create a socket connection to the server and just don't close it.So,when server has to send some notification to the client then it can do so through that socket.If Yes, then what is the need of web-sockets? And if No, then what exactly is the difference between web-sockets and sockets?

Comment: Technically - yes you are right - we don't need web-sockets per se, if we were to send 'some data' to client and if client can keep socket open. The problem is with http protocol - it's a request/response protocol and you'd not get a response from the server unless you request something. So it essentially means you've to keep 'asking' server for something new. Things like that can be solved with web-sockets - so it's just an extension to http protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the technology used on both the server and the client, I would definitely recommend using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Because:

- It's dead easy to set up
- Allows you to broadcast messages to virtually any number of clients
- Manages keep-alive and re-connections for you
- Provides an easy to use RPC style messaging pattern
- Picks the best connection method for you, depending on the type of connection and client
- Allows you to use javascript clients too (using a jQuery-like library)

Doing your own socket implementation for these kind of purposes is not very "2015" ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help,But the server is java based so I can't use SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sockets, the way I would go about this is to create a Listener in the client application, and for the server to send packets to this listener.

[This is a good resource to help you get started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx)